# Text matching in sql query (LIKE)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My Database:

```
    ID   place
-----------------------------------------------
    1    Bhowali
    2    Bangalore   
    3    Tumkur
```

**My Query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table 
WHERE  place LIKE '%bhovali'
```

Question is: many users search wrong keyword on that time the query result should match and output correct one..  in my above query ***bhovali*** is a wrong word the correct word is ***bhowali***. is there any way to get correct result from the query??..

Comment: How can we determine it should be `w` and not `v` in `bhovali`?

Comment: dont know.. bhovali is just an example of wrong word...

Comment: The bhovali and bhowali are just subjective. It could be anything else and therefore you cannot do this via a sql statement unless you knew the common mistakes made by the users. If there is pattern of user mistake, you can write logic at the backend/application layer and auto replace the common misspelt words or you can change the sql command to use the `replace` keyword.

Comment: @Rejesh R I understand you have already accepted an answer and all good and happpy ;) But do [check on this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/962d2/1).. doesn't seem to do what you need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be this can help  `SELECT * FROM   table  WHERE SOUNDEX(name) LIKE SOUNDEX('bhovali') ;`

Comment: @RajeshR Don't forget to make this as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really loaded question... short answer is no. SQL is made for giving you what you want, not what you might want.

You would have to develop some kind of intelligence engine to recognize that there are similar names and search for those as it occurs.

Comment: i thought its possible with default sql functions.. :( any way thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

in mysql you can use full text search if the column has the full text index as

select * from table match(name) against ('bhovali');